# Rollover Calendar

Tags: code-golf, date

*This is inspired by one of Downgoat's questions in Sandbox, where I suggested that he include April 31 as Pi day for people who use day/month format, only for him to inform me that there is no April 31!*

Given a date string in *month/day* format that might be invalid, output the correct date using rollover. (First rollover the month, then rollover the day).

**Examples:**

**"15/43"** - This reads as the 43rd day of the 15th month. First, we roll over the month to the next year, so we end up with 3 (March). Now, since March only has 31 days, we rollover the extra days to April, so we output the actual date as **"4/12"** (April 12th).

**"3/16"** - This is a valid date (March 16th). Return it as is.

**"12/64"** - Ah, so many fond memories from December 64th... December has 31 days, January has 31 days, so what I really mean is **"2/2"** (February 2nd).

**"19/99"** - First, the 19 becomes a 7 (July). July has 31 days, August has 31 days, September has 30 days, so the output is **"10/7"** (October 7th).

**"1/99999"** - A year has 365 days. 99999 (mod 365) = 354. The 354 day of the year is **"12/20"**.

**"9999999/10"** - Apparently, 9999999 (mod 12) = 3, so this is **"3/10"** (March 10th).

**Criteria:**

Input month is an integer > 0. Input day is an integer > 0. Year never needs to be specified, as such there are no leap years to deal with.

**Update:**

As I think it would overly simplify the challenge, calendar functions, such as those in the Java [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class, are banned. Date parsing/formatting functions are still allowed though.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/43045/)

Comment: Another important test case would be one with enough days to roll over more than 8 years, such that answers which use built-ins have to pay attention to those built-ins using leap years.

Comment: Oh, that answers that... I was just about to post a Mathematica answer which uses a built-in. :/

Comment: @Martin Sorry about that ;).

Comment: For reference, the Mathematica solution was still 90 bytes long (although that was massively dominated by the string processing). If you want to add such a test case nevertheless, `1/99999` should yield `12/19` I think.

Comment: @Martin Hm, I got 12/20. Which one of us is right?

Comment: @geokavel You're right, there was a bug in my code (in fact, I had 12/20 earlier).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## LabVIEW, 32 [LabVIEW Primitives](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490)

[image]

Comment: That was quick.

Comment: Can you assure me there are no calendar functions used here?

Comment: The good thing about LabVIEW is that its basically what it looks to be. First thing scans numbers from a string 2 modulos, the box is a switch case structure that gives out 28,30 or 31 and then it gets put together as a string again.

Answer (score 4):

### C#, <s>269</s> 223

```
string v(string n){var x=new[]{31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};var s=n.Split('/');Func<string,int> p=int.Parse;var m=p(s[0]);var d=p(s[1]);m=m>=12?m%12:m;while(d>x[m]){d-=x[m];m=++m>=12?m%12:m;}return(m==0?1:m)+"/"+d;}
```

**Edit**: Fixed to work for cases like 24/1, 36/1, etc. and golfed a little. Thanks for the comments, there are several places I saved a bit!

Ungolfed:

```
string v(string n)
{
    var x = new [] { 31 ,28, 31, 30, 31, 30,31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    var s = n.Split('/');
    Func<string,int> p = int.Parse;
    var m = p(s[0]);
    var d = p(s[1]);
    m = m >= 12 ? m % 12 : m;
    while (d > x[m])
    {
        d -= x[m];
        m = ++m >= 12 ? m % 12 : m;
    }
    return (m==0?1:m) + "/" + d;
}
```

Comment: First of all: Welcome to the community! I would guess you could save some Bytes by assigning the dictionary in a loop or using a switch function (no C# pro here though). Also directly printing ´m + "/" + d´ might help a little. And last (this might or might not work) using char* instead of string in the arguments.

Comment: This fails on certain test cases, e.g. `24/1`.

Comment: @Eumel thanks! Directly printing uses `Console.Write` which is more than `return`, and in C# I would use `char[]` as a replacement for `string`, but it's the same amount of chars, and makes splitting on the `/` more problematic. But, your note on the Dictionary did lead me to a way better version!

Answer (score 4):

### R, <s>208</s> 182 bytes

```
m=c(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31)
e=scan(sep="/");n=(e[1]/12-1)*12;if(!n%%12)n=12;if(n<0)n=e[1];j=e[2];while((j<-j-m[n])>0){n=n+1;if(n>12)n=1};j=m[n]+j;cat(n,j,sep="/")
```

Get the month by dividing by 12, then loop, removing the number of days of the current month until you get a negative number., inverse last step and print.

On multiple lines (need to use a file and source it):

```
m=c(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31)
e=scan(sep="/")
n=(e[1]/12-1)*12
if(!n%%12)n=12
if(n<0)n=e[1]
j=e[2]
while((j<-j-m[n])>0){n=n+1;if(n>12)n=1}
j=m[n]+j;cat(n,j,sep="/")
```

Comment: This is the message I get when trying to run your program in R: http://pastebin.com/dPh1n64a

Comment: Strange I'll recheck later

Comment: I also got this message. Your program seems to have problems with some months. Otherwise it's running. http://pastebin.com/g3BCUDi8

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I'm on road actually, I'll correct it

Comment: I understand. It seems like your program breaks with the "TRUE/FALSE" error message if the month is higher than 24.

Comment: Got it, should be n<1 as first if condition

Comment: @geokavel Sorry for the late feedback, I corrected the multiple of 12 months to give valid results now.

Comment: @plannapus Yes, thanks. It default to double according to my doc, but should not be a problem.

Comment: @Tensibai yes you're right, my bad (i should have remembered that the error message says that it expects "a real").

Answer (score 2):

## PHP >= 5.5, 181 bytes

```
list($m,$d)=explode("/",$argv[1]);$m%=12;$d%=365;$i=0;while($d>100)$d-=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][$i++];$m+=$i;echo date_create_from_format("m/d","$m/$d")->format("n/j");
```

PHP *almost* supports rollover with date parsing and formatting instructions alone. For example:

```
echo date_create_from_format("m/d","12/64")->format("n/j"); // Output: 2/2
```

However, once either number gets bigger than 100, PHP rejects parsing it and returns an error (probably for some arbitrary reason). So, the theory with this answer is to get it back down to where PHP will parse it, then submit it to [`date_create_from_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Ungolfed:

```
list($month, $day) = explode("/", $argv[1]);
$month = $month % 12;
$day = $day % 365;
$i = 0;
$days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
while($day > 31) $day -= $days[$i++];
$month += $i;
echo DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d", $month . "/" . $day)->format("n/j");
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/6AVYl)

Comment: You need to give me a way to input the date string,  or make it a function.

Comment: [GET parameters are not acceptable as an input method in PHP](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/7591#7591). You will need to either make this a function and pass the input as function parameters, or get input from `$argv` or STDIN.

Comment: @Mego Jeeze, give me some time to update my answer since the OP didn't state any requirements for input - it's simple enough to change `$t` to `$argv[1]` and now it reads from command line input.

Comment: The OP stating requirements for input is irrelevant; we have a list of default acceptable I/O methods (which I linked) so that challenge authors don't have to specify them on every challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 106 bytes

```js
s=>eval('q="030101001010";p=s.split`/`;for(d=i=p[1],m=p[0]-1;i--;d>n&&(m++,d-=n))n=31-q[m%=12];m+1+"/"+d')
```

### Explanation

```js
s=>
  eval(`              // use eval to enable for loop without needing to write {} or return
    q="030101001010"; // q = array of 31 - days in each month
    p=s.split\`/\`;   // p = array of [ month, day ]
    for(
      d=i=p[1],       // d = day
        m=p[0]-1;     // m = month - 1
      i--;            // loop for each day, this is more iterations than needed but extra
                      //     iterations do not affect the result and it's the shortest way
                      //     to guarantee all months have been subtracted from d, it also
                      //     ensures the loop runs at least once to get m % 12
      d>n&&(m++,d-=n) // if too many days, subtract the month's days and increment month
    )
      n=31-q[m%=12];  // n = number of days in month, get m % 12
    m+1+"/"+d         // return the result
  `)
```

### Test

```js
var solution = s=>eval('q="030101001010";p=s.split`/`;for(d=i=p[1],m=p[0]-1;i--;d>n&&(m++,d-=n))n=31-q[m%=12];m+1+"/"+d')
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="19/99" />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```