# Compute the Fibonomial Coefficient

Tags: code-golf, fibonacci, approximation

### Background

The Fibonacci sequence is defined as

$$f(1) = 1 \\ f(2) = 1 \\ f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)$$

The Fibonorial, similar to the factorial, is the product of the first \$n\$ Fibonacci numbers.

$$g(n) = f(1) \times f(2) \times ... \times f(n-1) \times f(n)$$

The Fibonomial coefficient, similar to the binomial coefficient is defined as

$$\begin{align}a(n, 0) & = 1 \\
a(n, k) & = \frac {g(n)} {g(n-k) \times g(k)} \\
& = \frac {f(n) \times f(n-1) \times ... \times f(n-k+1)} {f(1) \times f(2) \times ... \times f(k)}
\end{align}$$

### Task

Your goal is to create a function or program to compute the Fibonomial coefficient given two non-negative integers \$n\$ and \$k\$ with \$l \le n\$.

### Test Cases

```
a(0, 0) = 1
a(1, 1) = 1
a(2, 0) = 1
a(3, 2) = 2
a(8, 3) = 1092
a(11, 5) = 1514513
a(22, 7) = 7158243695757340957617
a(25, 3) = 49845401197200
a(50, 2) = 97905340104793732225
a(100, 1) = 354224848179261915075
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.
- Builtins are allowed.

### Related

- [A000045](http://oeis.org/A000045) - [Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence) - Fibonacci Sequence
- [A003266](http://oeis.org/A003266) - [Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86944/fibonacci-orial) - Fibonorial
- [A010048](http://oeis.org/A010048) - Fibonomial coefficient

Comment: If needed, [here](http://oeis.org/A010048/b010048.txt) is a webpage that lists the first `1335` values in the Fibonomial Coefficient sequence.

Comment: Is the `a(50, 2)` test case missing a leading `9`?

Comment: @SirBidenXVII Oh yes, you're right I missed a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
0+⁸Ð¡1ḊP
;_/Ç€:/
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MCvigbjDkMKhMeG4ilAKO18vw4figqw6Lw&input=&args=WzEwMCwxXQ)

Credits to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86945/48934) for the Fibonacci-orial helper link.

```
;_/Ç€:/     Main chain,  argument: [n,r]
 _/         Find n-r
;           Attach it to original: [n,r,n-r]
   Ç€       Apply helper link to each element, yielding [g(n),g(r),g(n-r)]
     :/     Reduce by integer division, yielding g(n)//g(r)//g(n-r)

0+⁸Ð¡1ḊP    Helper link, argument: n
0+⁸Ð¡1ḊP    Somehow return the n-th Fibonacci-orial.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 67 bytes

```
f=lambda n,a=1,b=1:n<1or a*f(n-1,b,a+b)
lambda n,k:f(n)/f(k)/f(n-k)
```

Call using `a(n,k)`. Uses @Dennis fibonorial answer (is that allowed?), and a straightforward implementation of the question otherwise.

Comment: All user content is licensed under CC-BY-SA, so as long as you provide attribution, you can reuse code from other answers. You can shorten your second lambda to `lambda n,k:f(n)/f(k)/f(n-k)`; naming it is not required.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 46 bytes

```haskell
l=0:scanl(+)1l;a%0=1;a%b=(a-1)%(b-1)*l!!a/l!!b
```

Outputs floats. Generates the infinite Fibonacci list. Then, does the binomial recusion, multiplying and dividing by elements from the Fibonacci list.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>77 57 55 52</s> 50 bytes

The first line is originally coming from the [Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence/89#89) challenge and was written by @Anon.

The second line was added in the [Fibonacci-orial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86944/fibonacci-orial/86961#86961) challenge by @ChristianSievers.

Now I added the third line. How much further will those challenges go?=)

```
f=1:scanl(+)1f
g=(scanl(*)1f!!)
n#k=g n/g(n-k)/g k
```

Thanks for 5 bytes @xnor!

Comment: Can you do `/` rather than `div`?

Comment: Hm yes, but that would end up in floating point numbers.

Comment: Oh, that is actually not disallowed, thanks=)

Comment: You can presumably divide twice to avoid parens.

Comment: Yes floats are allowed and there is no time limit so the recursive Fibonacci definition you used earlier was also valid.

Comment: It looks tempting to extract out the `scanl(?)1f` pattern in the first two lines, but `q o=scanl o 1f;f=1:q(+);g=(q(*)!!);n#k=g n/g(n-k)/g k` is 3 chars longer.

Comment: Now that we have this, the next thing could be the fibonomial transform  ;-)

Comment: Or maybe some kind of Fibonomial integration >.>

Answer (score 3):

## C, 206 bytes:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
uint64_t F(x){return x<1 ? 0:x==1 ? 1:F(x-1)+F(x-2);}uint64_t G(H,B){uint64_t P=1;for(B=3;B<=H;B++)P*=F(B);return P;}main(U,Y){scanf("%d %d",&U,&Y);printf("%llu\n",G(U)/(G(U-Y)*G(Y)));}
```

Upon execution, asks for 2 space separated integers as input. The `#include` preprocessor is *required*, as without it, `uint_64` is not a valid type, and the only other way to make this work for fairly big outputs is using `unsigned long long` return types for both the `F` (Fibonacci) and `G` (Fibonorial) functions, which is much longer than just including the `<inttypes.h>` and using 3 `uint64_t` type declarations. However, even with that, it stops working correctly at input values `14 1` (confirmed by using [this](http://oeis.org/A010048/b010048.txt), which lists the first `1325` values in the Fibonomial Coefficient sequence), most likely because the Fibonacci and/or Fibnorial representation of numbers `15` and above overflow the 64-bit integer type used.

[C It Online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/nSqk4k)

Comment: It's probably since the Fibonorial of 15 overflows `uint_64`

Answer (score 3):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), <s>75</s> 64 bytes

```
a->b->(g->g((a-b+1)|>a)/g(1|>b))(n->n.map(Math.fib).reduce((*)))
```

### Usage

```
cheddar> var f = a->b->(g->g((a-b+1)|>a)/g(1|>b))(n->n.map(Math.fib).reduce((*)))
cheddar> f(11)(5)
1514513
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
1ti2-:"yy+]vtPi:)w5M)/p
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MXRpMi06Inl5K112dFBpOil3NU0pL3A&input=MTEKNQ)

#### Explanation

```
1t      % Push 1 twice
i2-:    % Take input n. Generate vector [1 2 ... n-2]
"       % Repeat n-2 times
  yy    %   Push the top two elements again
  +     %   Add them
]       % End
v       % Concatenate into column vector of first n Fibonacci numbers
tP      % Duplicate and reverse
i:      % Take input k. Generate vector [1 2 ... k]
)       % Apply index to get last k Fibonacci numbers
w       % Swap to move vector of first n Fibonacci numbers to top
5M      % Push [1 2 ... k] again
)       % Apply index to get first k Fibonacci numbers
/       % Divide element-wise
p       % Product of vector. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 120 bytes

Some more golfing is probably be possible, so comments are of course welcomed !
I used my answer of the [Fibonacci-orial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/87256/56131) question in the begining of the code :

```
A=function(n,k){p=(1+sqrt(5))/2;f=function(N){x=1;for(n in 1:N){x=prod(x,(p^n-(-1/p)^n)/sqrt(5))};x};f(n)/(f(k)*f(n-k))}
```

**Ungolfed :**

```
A=function(n,k){
p=(1+sqrt(5))/2
    f=function(N){
        x=1
        for(n in 1:N){
           x=prod(x,(p^n-(-1/p)^n)/sqrt(5))
                     }
        x
        }

f(n)/(f(k)*f(n-k))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java: <strike>304</strike> <strike>260</strike> 257

I saved some bytes by compacting the memoization function a bit and removing `f(n)` entirely, replacing it with direct array access.

```java
BigInteger[]c;BigInteger a(int n,int k){m(n);return g(n).divide(g(n-k)).divide(g(k));}BigInteger g(int n){return n<3?BigInteger.ONE:g(n-1).multiply(c[n-1]);}void m(int n){c=new BigInteger[n];for(int i=0;i<n;++i)c[i]=(i<2)?BigInteger.ONE:c[i-2].add(c[i-1]);}
```

Unfortunately, `BigInteger` is required due to overflows and I had to add memoization. Even on a generation 6 i7, it was taking *way* too long to run with large inputs.

Ungolfed, with boilerplate `class` and `main` code:

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class ComputeTheFibonomialCoefficient {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // @formatter:off
    String[][] testData = new String[][] {
      { "0", "0", "1" },
      { "1", "1", "1" },
      { "2", "0", "1" },
      { "3", "2", "2" },
      { "8", "3", "1092" },
      { "11", "5", "1514513" },
      { "22", "7", "7158243695757340957617" },
      { "25", "3", "49845401197200" },
      { "50", "2", "97905340104793732225" },
      { "100", "1", "354224848179261915075" }
    };
    // @formatter:on

    for (String[] data : testData) {
      System.out.println("a(" + data[0] + ", " + data[1] + ")");
      System.out.println("  Expected -> " + data[2]);
      System.out.print("    Actual -> ");
      System.out.println(new ComputeTheFibonomialCoefficient().a(
          Integer.parseInt(data[0]), Integer.parseInt(data[1])));
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  // Begin golf

  BigInteger[] c;

  BigInteger a(int n, int k) {
    m(n);
    return g(n).divide(g(n - k)).divide(g(k));
  }

  BigInteger g(int n) {
    return n < 3 ? BigInteger.ONE : g(n - 1).multiply(c[n - 1]);
  }

  void m(int n) {
    c = new BigInteger[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      c[i] = (i < 2) ? BigInteger.ONE : c[i - 2].add(c[i - 1]);
  }
  // End golf
}
```

Program output:

```
a(0, 0)
  Expected -> 1
    Actual -> 1

a(1, 1)
  Expected -> 1
    Actual -> 1

a(2, 0)
  Expected -> 1
    Actual -> 1

a(3, 2)
  Expected -> 2
    Actual -> 2

a(8, 3)
  Expected -> 1092
    Actual -> 1092

a(11, 5)
  Expected -> 1514513
    Actual -> 1514513

a(22, 7)
  Expected -> 7158243695757340957617
    Actual -> 7158243695757340957617

a(25, 3)
  Expected -> 49845401197200
    Actual -> 49845401197200

a(50, 2)
  Expected -> 97905340104793732225
    Actual -> 97905340104793732225

a(100, 1)
  Expected -> 354224848179261915075
    Actual -> 354224848179261915075
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 70 bytes

```
a=n=>n<2?1:a(--n)+a(--n);b=n=>n?a(--n)*b(n):1;c=n=>k=>b(n)/b(n-k)/b(k)
```

Call using `c(n)(k)`, pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 72 bytes

Special thanks to @st0le for [the really short Fibonacci generation code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111/52194).

```
->n,k{f=[a=b=1,1]+(1..n).map{b=a+a=b}
r=->i{f[i,k].inject:*}
k>0?r[n-k]/r[0]:1}
```

Answer (score 1):

## dc, 67 bytes

```
?skdsn[si1d[sadlarla+zli>b*]sbzli>b*]dsgxsplnlk-lgxsqlklgxlprlqr*/f
```

Input is taken as space-delimited decimal constants on a single line.

This uses my [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86944/fibonacci-orial/86949#86949) to the `/Fibon(acci-)?orial/` question, which multiplies all numbers on the stack in the last step, requiring the other numbers to be stored elsewhere while the other Fibonorials are calculated.

```
?       # Take input from stdin
skdsn   # Store second number in register `k'; store a copy of first number in register `n'
[si1d[sadlarla+zli>b*]sbzli>b*] # Compute Fibonorial of top-of-stack, multiplying
                                #   until stack depth is 1
dsgx    # Store a copy of this function as g and execute it: g(n)
sp      # Store g(n) in register `p'
lnlk-   # Compute n-k
lgx     # Compute g(n-k)
sq      # Store g(n-k) in register `q'
lk lgx  # Compute g(k)
        # Top ---Down--->
lp      #  g(n)    g(k)
r       #  g(k)    g(n)
lq      #  g(n-k)  g(k)    g(n)
r       #  g(k)    g(n-k)  g(n)
*       # (g(k)g(n-k))     g(n)
/       #  g(n)/(g(k)g(n-k))
f       # Dump stack to stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 53 bytes

```
!x=[([1 1;1 0]^n)[2]for n=1:x]|>prod;n\k=!n/!(n-k)/!k
```

Credits to @Lynn for his [Fibonorial answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86970/41247).

Answer (score 1):

**Axiom 108 bytes**

```
b(n,k)==(n<=k or k<1=>1;reduce(*,[fibonacci(i) for i in (n-k+1)..n])/reduce(*,[fibonacci(i) for i in 1..k]))
```

some test

```
(34) -> b(0,0),b(1,1),b(2,0),b(3,2),b(8,3),b(11,5),b(22,7)
   Compiling function b with type (NonNegativeInteger,
      NonNegativeInteger) -> Fraction Integer
   Compiling function b with type (PositiveInteger,PositiveInteger) ->
      Fraction Integer
   Compiling function b with type (PositiveInteger,NonNegativeInteger)
       -> Fraction Integer

   (34)  [1,1,1,2,1092,1514513,7158243695757340957617]
                                                 Type: Tuple Fraction Integer
(35) -> b(25,3),b(50,2),b(100,1)

   (35)  [49845401197200,97905340104793732225,354224848179261915075]
```

### Type: Tuple Fraction Integer

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 30 bytes

```
(f=Fibonorial)@#/f[#-#2]/f@#2&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
;ạ/RÆḞP€÷/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU67CgJBDKy9r1iwUVi4JJtcNoj/ILZiaSP@gK2F9lZWgr29j/bwQ84fWffg5LRKZiYzk/Vqs9mmNGmel3Je75v7efbeXetbmepDXl7H5nFKaVEMRuAdjL0buqnDDNE7/IH0rwbvqIOUYfQufFWwlsHsly8lyIKhTckx2rGKEolDZaKigSHPCrU9kj6NLbIwIJoSQBYF@mZTA8lOBFYLGohI2mqA/vcgTMSRI6pRhYYCKsXyAw)

### How it works

```
;ạ/RÆḞP€÷/ - Main link. Takes [n, r] on the left
 ạ/        - Calculate |n-r|
;          - Yield [n, r, |n-r|]
   R       - Convert each to a range
    ÆḞ     - For each integer i, yield the i'th Fibonacci number
      P€   - Get the product of each array, yielding [g(n), g(r), g(n-r)]
        ÷/ - Yield g(n) ÷ g(r) ÷ g(n-r) = g(n) ÷ (g(r) × g(n-r))
```